# Sed error No such file or directory on Github Actions

Tags: linux, curl, sed, github-actions

I am using a simple GitHub actions to update a value in a file, then upload that file using a curl command. However, GitHub keeps telling me that the file can't be found.

I have ensure it is there by printing `ls` and also testing locally. It works locally without n issue (I am using a Mac).

Here is my GitHub Actions file:

```
name: Deploy Preview
"on": pull_request

env:
  GRAPHQL_SECRET: ${{ secrets.graphql_secret }}
  GRAPHQL_API: ${{ secrets.graphql_api }}

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy Schema
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Upload Schema
        run: yarn upload-schema
```

and the `yarn upload-schema` script looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i "" "s|verification_key|${GRAPHQL_SECRET}|" ./schema.graphql
curl -X POST "${GRAPHQL_API}"/admin/schema --data-binary '@schema.graphql'
```

Do I need to use a different `sed` command for the linux system on GitHub Actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I had to use a separate type of sed command. I am not very familiar with sed to not too sure what the differences are.

```
sed -i "s/verification_key/${GRAPHQL_SECRET}/g" schema.graphql
curl -X POST "${GRAPHQL_API}"/admin/schema --data-binary '@schema.graphql'
```